# Error while using STATet / R (in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

I have just finished installing R 3.1.0, Eclipse Luna, STATeT 3.4 (with RJ 2.0).

I have followed the worksheet, during which I configured an R environment and ran an R console.

I have tried testing all this with Eclipse. When I make a R-Script-File, with a bit of simple code in it such as: `x <- 1`, it runs fine if I select the line and I click on "Run selection in R".

If I click on the green arrow ("Run"), and then "Run script in R submitting directly", everything works fine.

**However**, when I click on the green arrow ("Run") and then "Run script in R via source", I get:

```
An error occured. Connection to R engine is closed.
```

I also get the message: `An error occurred when preparing element tagging for file '/Test Coursera/Test1.R'.`

**Why does that happen?**

Additionally, if I try clicking on "Run File in R via Command", I get the same error, plus this message:

```
Communication error detail. Send: null
```

And there are tons on lines under the "Exception Stack Trace" line, the first ones being:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

**On a side note**, I don't get at all what I should pick as my "working directory". In R, when I type "getwd()", I get "C:/Users/charl_000/Documents", so that's what I kept in Eclipse. But shouldn't I pick the same folder as my Eclipse workspace? What is the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Working directory" is where your R code is (projects).

Comment: Does this also happen if you use the shortcut (CTRL+r+s)?

Comment: Yes, it does. (it opens a list of shortcuts on the right, and then I get to choose between the different options) The one with CTRL+R+S does the same thing as what I described. (R shuts down)